# Why shift the array in the &max subroutine example in Learning Perl, 6th ed., ch. 4

Tags: perl

Why is the array shifted at the beginning of the subroutine?

```
sub max {
    my($max_so_far) = shift @_;
    foreach (@_) {
        if ($_ > $max_so_far) {
           $max_so_far = $_;
        }
    }
    $max_so_far;
}
```

Is it just to give $max_so_far an initial value? The program runs exactly the same with

```
    my($max_so_far) = undef;
```

Is there a particular reason to shift the array to start with? (I ask because I spent about 10 min trying to figure out why that shift was essential to the subroutine.)

Comment: Doesn't setting `$max_so_far` to undef cause an undefined warning on the first comparison? You should probably `use warnings` if you are learning perl.

Comment: Yes, it's there to give an initial value to $max_so_far.

Comment: Is Learning Perl still using explicit `$_` and implicit returns?

Comment: I can guess what `use warnings` is, but they haven't introduced it yet. (Still only ch. 4!)

Comment: Is it really written `my($max_so_far) = shift @_;` instead of `my $max_so_far = shift @_;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to initialise the return value for the function and something the rest of the function can compare against.

Consider some scenarios and trace through the code. For example, say it is invoked like this:

```
my $max = max(1,2,3);
```

Inside max, the first line sets $max_so_far to 1 and @_ becomes (2,3). Now when we run through the foreach loop we have an initial value and avoid undef errors. It first compares $max_so_far to 2, updates it to 2, and so on.

Another example is if max is invoked like this:

```
my $max = max(1);
```

Inside max, the first line sets $max_so_far to 1 and @_ becomes (). When we hit the foreach loop, it has nothing to iterate through and just returns the initial value $max_so_far.

Another example is if max is invoked like this:

```
my $max = max();
```

Inside max, the first line sets $max_so_far to undef because @_ is empty. There's nothing to iterate through in the foreach loop, so the function just returns undef.

Comment: What was confusing me was that it seemed like they _had_ to shift the array before they could iterate through it, and I couldn't figure out why. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: A formal way to look at it is that structurally, `max` is a reduce (aka a left fold) on a list, with the operation `(a > b) ? a : b`. With a reduce you usually either want to start with a natural identity of the operator, or only draw values from the list. If that operation has an identity it's the value -∞, which works just fine assuming you know how to represent it, but drawing values only from the list works just fine too, and that's what the `shift` is doing in this iteratively unrolled version of the reduce.

Answer (score 7):

The program does not run exactly the same if you initialize `$max_so_far` to `undef`. What if all of the input values are negative numbers?

Comment: In other words, doing it with undef is the same as adding "undef" to the list to be scanned.

Comment: Or what if you were writing the `min` function instead?

Comment: Yeah, when I use `undef` it returns a blank if all the numbers entered are negative. I hadn't tried that.

Comment: Actually @MarcAdler it returns `undef`, not blank. ( `undef` becomes `''` in string context ) It also would return `undef` if all of the inputs were `0` which is equal (numerically) to `undef`. (`0 == undef`)